# Change default controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a modules:

`app/code/local/MyStore/Welcome`

And in this module, I have a controller like:

`MyStore_Welcome_IndexController`

From my current knowledge, I see at the beginning `Magento` load `Mage_Cms_IndexController` controller as the default controller.

Now I want to load `MyStore_Welcome_IndexController` controller as default.

How can I do that?

---

**Update:**

I've found a way to do using admin feature:
From the menu you chose: System/Configuration/Web:
You continue to choose: "Default Page" => "Default Web URL" to field the module:
[image: Image to show how to config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that your controller `extends Mage_Cms_IndexController` and then override that default controller via the controller overloading method. In this method you will create a plugin as per usual, but you need to do the following:

- add the declaration `require_once()` at the top with the relative path to the controller you're overloading. E.g. :

  ```
  require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
  class MyClass_OverloadedCheckout_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
  ```
- Create any class methods or properties that you may want to add in addition to the default.
- in your config.xml add the following lines *outside* of the `<global>` node:

  ```
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <myclass_overloadedcheckout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Myclass_OverloadedCheckout</module>
                    <frontName>OverloadedCheckout</frontName>
                </args>
            </myclass_overloadedcheckout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
  ```

Something to remember - if you rewrite any default methods you need to `return parent::{methodname}` either before or after your injected functionality to ensure that the default behaviors continue to operate.

Comment: I will try and inform to you the result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did not have time to test it. Very thanks for your help. And I give you +50 reputation. When I back to this feature I will try it and if it works I will tell you.

Comment: This is not the correct method for rewriting action controllers. How would that frontname ever be generated by the system?

Comment: If this isn't the correct method then I've been doing it incorrectly and it has been working for me for 2+ years...

Comment: @Ben - if this is not the correct method, why don't you suggest the correct method below in a new answer???

Answer (score 1):

You should think again if you really want to do it because it is a huge change, but you could simply override the `Mage_Cms_IndexController`. How you can override a controller, you can find e.g. [here](http://www.spinonesolutions.com/2010/03/magento-controller-override/).

Anyway, I would try to solve the problem another way. Maybe you can use the Event/Observer Pattern?

Comment: I want to change `Mage_Cms_IndexController` to `MyStore_Welcome_IndexController`, I don't want to override it. How can I do it, using code?